# An application of the inverse function theorem?

Tags: multivariable-calculus

I am trying to prove the statement:

> Suppose that $\mathbf{g}$ is of class $\mathcal{C}^1$, with $J\mathbf{g}(\mathbf{t}) \neq 0$, for all $t \in \triangle$, where $\triangle$ is the open set over which the vector valued function is defined. Given $\mathbf{x} \notin \mathbf{g}(\triangle)$, let $\mathbf{\psi}(\mathbf{t}) = 
> || \mathbf{x} - \mathbf{g}(\mathbf{t}) ||^2$ . Show that $\mathbf{D}\mathbf{\psi}(\mathbf{t}) \neq 0$ for all $\mathbf{t} \in \triangle$.

I have done some work on the side, and I suspect the statement can be proved without invoking the condition that the Jacobian is zero. Assuming the mapping $\mathbf{\psi}$ has the zero matrix as its derivative matrix, I tried applying the definition of differentiability to the vector valued function, $\mathbf{\psi}$, and used the conditions that $\mathbf{g}$ is a differentiable, continuous transformation. Some scribbles on the side seem to show that upon opening the expression $|| \mathbf{x} - \mathbf{g}(\mathbf{t}) ||^2$, the conclusion seems to follow.

I'm not sure if the above reasoning above is correct, but I'm trying to see if the statement can be inferred directly from the Inverse Function Theorem, since it obviously implies in this case (the Jacobian is non zero). I'm not sure how to complete the argument using the Inverse Function Theorem, though.

Any hints? Please give suggestions only.

Answer (score 0):

I'll denote $\langle \cdot, \cdot \rangle$ by the usual dot product. Recall that $\|x - g(t)\|^2 = (x-g(t)) \cdot (x-g(t))$ and now we compute the differential.

\begin{align*} D\psi(t) = D((x-g(t)) \cdot (x-g(t)) &= 2D(x-g(t)) (x-g(t))\\ \\ &= 2Dg(t)(x-g(t)) \\ \\ & \not = 0 \end{align*}

To apply the Inverse Function Theorem you need first that the differential of your map at some point is invertible i.e you need to compute the derivative first. In this case, to be invertible you have to have rank $1$ since $\psi: \Delta \to \mathbb{R}^1$. But rank $1$ simply means $D\psi(t) \not = 0 \iff Dg(t) \not = 0$, so yes you do need that condition.